# iframes sidebar full page height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I would like to split my HTML page in a sidebar and a main. The width should be about 20%-80%, the height should be the full page. This is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body>

<div class="menu">
<iframe src="menu.html" name="iframe_sidebar">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
<iframe name="iframe_main">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

menu.html

```
<html>
  <body>
  <h3>Search</h3>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="iframe_main">
    Google
  </a><br>
  <a href="http://www.bing.com/" target="iframe_main">
    Bing
  </a><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
.menu{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left; 
}
.box{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float:left; 
}
```

The result is here. What am I doing wrong?

[image: iframe]

Comment: 20% and 80% of what? You need to set a width of a parent/ancestor. However, having said that I'd recommend you look at say CSS grid to do the layout as it will cope with gaps and so on more easily. Also are you sure that an iframe for the menu is actually going to work and be what you want?

Comment: If I click on one of the links in the bar, it loads the page on the right, so it somehow works.
But the sizes of the boxes are not what I want.